# Primefaces UploadFile no hace llamada al servidor

Tags: java, primefaces, fileupload

Estoy intentando usar el UploadFile de Primefaces pero cuando selecciono una imagen no me llama al servidor. He usado el inspector del navegador pero no se hace ninguna llamada.

He intentado probar todo lo que se dice [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded) pero nada ha funcionado

Mi xhtml resumido es

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <p:fileUpload listener="#{modificarUsuarioBean.cambiarAvatar}"
                    auto="true" update="messages avatarModificar"
                    label="#{messages['usuario.accion.CAMBIAR_AVATAR']}"
                    styleClass="" />
</h:form>
```

Mi web.xml

```
<!-- UPLOAD -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Versiones de software:

- Primefaces 11
- JSF 2.2
- Spring 5.3
- Commons Fileupload 1.4

Un saludo y gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estaba incluyendo mi propia versión de jquery en la página y daba un error de javascript que no habia visto.

La solución es no incluir mi propia versión de jquery ya que Primefaces lo incluye directamente.

[Fuente](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=61848)